# JAPANESE LANGUAGE METAに7ページ目がありません?

Tags: discussion

いつの間にか JAPANESE LANGUAGE METAに迷い込んでしまった時のこと、ふと見ると7ページ目がありません。

なぜでしょうか?

スクリーンショット
https://ibb.co/F6Z0rPr

Comment: 私は見てるよ　https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=newest&page=7

Comment: Oh!ありました。見れます、今。(リンク先から行きました、リンクThanks.)なぜ昨日は見れない状況だったのか、とても不思議です。

Answer (score 3):

There is a finite number of questions, so there will always be a finite number of pages. If you apply a filter to the questions, the list of questions will be shorter. For example, the "Unanswered" tab has currently 181 questions:

[image: question filter]

which makes it 7 pages at (up to) 30 questions each:

[image: number of pages]

I suspect, you were looking at this filter with the setting (visible in your screenshot) of listing 30 questions per page when there were maybe ≤180 unanswered questions, giving 6 pages, which explains why there would be no page 7...